# JS RegEx challenge: replacing recurring patterns of commas and numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am fiddling with a program to convert Japanese addresses into romaji (latin alphabet) for use in an emergency broadcast system for foreigners living in a Japanese city.

Emergency evacuation warnings are sent out to lists of areas all at once. I would like to be able to copy/paste this Japanese list of areas and spit out the romanized equivalent.

example Japanese input:
3条4～12丁目、15～18条12丁目、2、3条5丁目
(this list is of three areas, where 条(jo) and 丁目(chome) indicate block numbers in north-south and east-west directions, respectively)

The numbers are fine as they are, and I have already written code to replace the characters 条 and 丁目 with their romanized equivalents. My program currently outputs the first two areas (correctly) as "3-jo 4~12-chome" and "15~18-jo 12-chome"

However, I would like to replace patterns like that in the last area "**2、5条6丁目**" (meaning blocks 2 and 5 of 6-chome) such that the output reads "**2&5-jo 6-chome**"

The regular expression that denotes this pattern is `\d*、\d*` (note the Japanese format comma)

I am still getting used to regex - how can I replace the comma found in all `\d*、\d*` patterns with an "&"? Note that I can't simply replace all commas because they are also used to separate areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to isolate sequences like `15、18` and replace all commas in them.

```
text = "3条4～12丁目、15～18条12丁目、2、3条5丁目";
text.
  replace(/(?:\d+、)+\d+/g, function(match) {
    return match.replace(/、/g, "&");
  }).
  replace(/条/g, '-jō ').
  replace(/丁目/g, '-chōme').
  replace(/～/g, '-').
  replace(/、/g, ', ')
// => "3-jō 4-12-chōme, 15-18-jō 12-chōme, 2&3-jō 5-chōme"
```

(Also... Where the heck do you live that has 丁 well-ordered by cardinal directions? Where I live, addresses are a mess... :P )

(Also also, thanks to sainaen for nitpicking my regexps into perfection :) )

Comment: I think `/、/` should be replaced with `/、/g` in `return match.replace(/、/, "&")` , to allow groups of more than two numbers. (like, "1、2、3条5丁目".)

Comment: Also, in `/(?:\d+、)*\d+/g`, I think it may be faster to expect at least one group with comma:   `/(?:\d+、)+\d+/g`, because then replace function will not be called when not needed.

Comment: Ooh and thanks for the fancy, more correct romanization with the o's (though these alerts may be issued by text message so I think I will keep the simple o's)

I see! You use a function in the replaced parameter. 

@sainaen: thank you for the added felxibility! Nice catch

(P.S. The city is Sapporo - a young city co-designed by Americans, explaining the easy grid system :P)